# questions about scraping a review website

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am currently crawling a review site with beautiful soup.

the review page contains reviews from different students,
and each student would evaluate the school on several aspects.

therefore, the structure of the page generally looks like:

1. student A - title A:

   - aspect 1
   - comment toward aspect 1
   - aspect2
   - commet on aspect 2
   - aspect3
   - commet on aspect 3
2. student B - title B:

   - aspect 1
   - comment toward aspect 1
   - aspect2
   - commet on aspect 2
   - aspect4
   - commet on aspect 4

## some students only made comments on particular aspects. the aspects they dont comment on will not be shown on the website.

---

each review in code

```
     <!-- mod-reviewTop -->
     <div class="mod-reviewTop">
      <!-- mod-reviewTop-inner -->
      <div class="mod-reviewTop-inner">
       <dl>
        <dd>
         <div class="mod-reviewTitle" itemprop="summary">
            title 1 : It was ok.
         </div>
        </dd>
       </dl>
        <!-- /mod-reviewItem -->
     </div>
     <!-- /mod-reviewTop -->
     <!-- mod-reviewBottom -->
     <div class="mod-reviewBottom">
      <!-- mod-reviewList-list -->
      <div class="mod-reviewList-list js-review-detail" itemprop="description">
       <!-- js-mod-reviewList-list -->
       <div class="js-mod-reviewList-list">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <div class="mod-reviewTitle3">
           Total Evaluation
          </div>
          <div class="mod-reviewList-txt">
           We can freely choose the course we want, and thus a lot of different knowledge can be learned.
          </div>
         </li>
         <li>
          <div class="mod-reviewTitle3">
           Course
          </div>
          <div class="mod-reviewList-txt">
           the courses are good.
          </div>
         </li>
         <li>
          <div class="mod-reviewTitle3">
           Lab
          </div>
          <div class="mod-reviewList-txt">
           we don’t join lab in the first 2 year.
          </div>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <!-- /js-mod-reviewList-list -->
      </div>
      <!-- /mod-reviewList-list -->
     </div>
     <!-- /mod-reviewBottom -->
```

you can see that even though the title of aspects are different, they all start with **'div class="mod-reviewTitle3" '** , and the comments all start with **'div class="mod-reviewList-txt"'**.
my question is that how do i write good code to store these information into a data set:

| title | aspect1 comment | aspect2 comment
     A       good               very nice

i have tried the code below, but aspect comment in each block doesnt work well

```
datatest = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mod-reviewTop"})
datatest1 = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mod-reviewBottom"})

for item in datatest:
    a = item.select('.mod-reviewTitle')       
    c = item.select('.mod-reviewTitle3')
    d = item.select('.mod-reviewList-txt')  
    g = item.select('.js-mod-reviewList-list')
    f= item.select('.mod-reviewItem')   

for i in range(len(a)):
    f1= f[i].text[7]
    f2= f[i].text[17]
    f3= f[i].text[26]
    f4= f[i].text[37]
    f5= f[i].text[46]
    f6= f[i].text[55]
    f7= f[i].text[63]

    print a[i].text
    print f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7
    for item in datatest1:
        for k in range(len(g)):
            print g[k].text
            print e[k].text
            print k
```

i regard this as a programming problem..
i have try loops but didnt work well

if you can kindly give me some reference or how the structure shall work logically, pls kindly leave me a comment.. thanks

Comment: You should only talk about the problem you have not write the whole story here. what is your question? how to write good code to store information in a dataset? what's good code? anyways you can store data in datasets using pandas, you can use xlwt to write in an excel file, or you can write in a text file with your own separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tips:

- You should attach `aspects` and `comments` to corresponding `titles`, which means you store them together by using a proper data structure. like this(Just one possible way)

  `[
      (title1,[
                  (aspect1, comment1),
                  (aspect2, comment2),
                  ...
              ]),
      (title2,[
                  (aspect1, comment1),
                  (aspect2, comment2),
                  ...
              ]),
      ...
  ]`
- So when retrieving data you want, organize operations with nested `for` loops. i.e. Once you find an aspect, for example, try to get the  corresponding comment and store them together. Escape finding all aspects, then all comments.

## Code

Here is a demo.

```
blocks = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mod-reviewTop"})
contents = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mod-reviewBottom"})
data = []

for i,block in enumerate(blocks):
    aspects = []
    title = str(block.find('div',{'class':'mod-reviewTitle'}).text).strip()
    for aspect_block in contents[i].find_all('li'):
        aspect = str(aspect_block.find('div',{'class':'mod-reviewTitle3'}).text).strip()
        comment = str(aspect_block.find('div',{'class':'mod-reviewList-txt'}).text).strip()
        aspects.append((aspect,comment))
    data.append((title,aspects))

print data

with open("output.txt","w") as file:
    for title, aspects in data:
        file.write(title)
        for aspect in aspects:
            file.write('|'+aspect[0]+'\t'+aspect[1])
        file.write('\n')
```